# Boolean algebra manipulation

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am having a hard time showing that the following is valid:

$$(x+y+z)(x'+y+z')(x+y')(y'+z) = x'y'z' + xy'z' + xyz$$  I've tried using Dual to get: $$(x'y'z') + (xy'z) + (x'y) + (y+z')$$
But that seems to lead my to a dead end because I can only come up with: $$x'y'z' + xy'z + xyz$$

I have no idea how to get that last z in complement form.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Unless there's a typo in your question, the equality can't be proved because it doesn't hold. For x=y=z=0 the left-hand side evaluates to 0, while the right-hand side evaluates to 1.

Comment: Yep, looks like there is! Apparently, I am incapable of copying down questions correctly. The right hand side is supposed to be:x'y'z + xy'z' + xyz -Thanks for pointing it out!